# How do I use preventDefault() in a named function?

Tags: jquery

So far, the code I have is:

```
function behaviourAdd (){
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "folders/jq_set_folder_as_behaviour/add/" + $("a#behaviour").data("folder"),
        success: function () {
            $('a#behaviour')
            .addClass('active')
            .attr('title', "Remove a Behaviour")
            .unbind('click')
            .bind('click', behaviourRemove);
        }
    });
}

function behaviourRemove (){
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "folders/jq_set_folder_as_behaviour/remove/" + $("a#behaviour").data("folder"),
        success: function () {
            $('a#behaviour')
            .removeClass('active')
            .attr('title', "Add a Behaviour")
            .unbind('click')
            .bind('click', behaviourAdd);
        }
    });
}

if($('a#behaviour').hasClass('active') == true) {
    $('a#behaviour').bind('click', behaviourRemove);
} else {
    $('a#behaviour').bind('click', behaviourAdd);
}
```

All of which works perfectly. However, I'm trying to prevent the default click behaviour, but everything I've tried fails.

After many searches, the only context I can find is:

```
$("a#behaviour").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Which doesn't apply to me because I'm using a named function, which I assume is the reason this isn't working.

While I'm able to pass the event data:

```
$('a#behaviour').bind('click', behaviourRemove(event));
```

I get an error as soon as I use it within either of the functions:

```
function behaviourAdd (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

So any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accept the `event` parameter in the "named function" :

```
function behaviourRemove (event){
   event.preventDefault();
```

It will be given to behaviourRemove when you set the event handling as in

```
$('a#behaviour').bind('click', behaviourRemove);
```

As an aside : it's faster to use `$('#behaviour')` than `$('a#behaviour')`.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the reply. So the trick is to not actually pass the event in the bind() function. Okay. It strikes me as being weird, but never mind. So long as it works!

Comment: That's not really weird : the idea is that you pass a function to `bind`, and that `bind` calls the function and provides the argument. The function is passed using its name.

Answer (score 0):

Just put return value as false like

```
function behaviourAdd (){
    return false;
    -------------
}
```

you can also use predefault method in the named functions also

```
function behaviourRemove (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    -------- 
}
```